# Formatting floating number

Tags: javascript, formatting, numbers

I have this function here:

```js
import {
  TextInputField,
  TextInputValue
} from "../types";
import formatNumber from "utils/formatNumber";
import formatString from "utils/formatString";

const getFormattedValue = (field: TextInputField, value: TextInputValue) => {
  let formattedValue;
  const NUMBER_WITH_POSSIBLE_FLOATING_PART_REGEX = new RegExp(
    /^-{0,1}\d+[,.]{0,1}\d*$/,
  );
  const {
    format,
    inputType,
    componentType
  } = field;

  const formatIsString = format && typeof format === "string";
  const isNotSelectOrDate =
    componentType !== "Select" && componentType !== "Date";
  const isNotANumber = inputType !== "number";

  if (isNotANumber && formatIsString && isNotSelectOrDate) {
    const isNumberButString =
      value && String(value).match(NUMBER_WITH_POSSIBLE_FLOATING_PART_REGEX);

    formattedValue = isNumberButString ?
      formatNumber(format, String(value)) :
      formatString(format, value && String(value));
  }
  return formattedValue;
};
export default getFormattedValue;
```

and moreover this:

```js
import memoizee from "memoizee";
import formatter from "number-format.js";
import isNumber from "lodash/isNumber";
import Logger from "../Logger";

const formatNumber = (format: string, number: string): string => {
  // we are receiving value which will contain , (comma) as a decimal separator.
  // therefore we need to replace it with . (dot) to treat it as a number
  number = number.replace(",", ".");

  if (!format || !isNumber(+number)) {
    Logger.info("Provide format and number", format, number);
    return number;
  }

  // if user is typing the value we don`t want to round values such us '22,' or '22,0' to '22'
  // we are checking if it ends with dot because we replace , with . few lines back.
  // in such case we need to return what we get but replace . with , back again because we want
  // user to see comma not a dot
  if (number.endsWith(".") || number.endsWith(".0")) {
    return number.replace(".", ",");
  }

  const numberToFormat = parseFloat(number);

  if (Number.isNaN(numberToFormat)) {
    Logger.info("Not a number", format, number);
    return number;
  }

  const formattedNumber = formatter(format, numberToFormat); // here by using formatter dot will be changed automatically to comma
  return formattedNumber;
};

export default memoizee(formatNumber);
```

Can this be done better ? Actually I do not really like this approach

Comment: Can you provide more info, maybe a more detailed description of how and why you want this data?